# AWS Cloudformation Windows 2016 EC2 S3 silent install

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, user-data, silent-installer, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have architecture created using CloudFormation utilizing Windows 2016 EC2 server and S3, written in JSON.  I have 7 executables uploaded onto my S3 bucket.  I can manually silently install everything from a Powershell for AWS prompt, once I Remote into the EC2. I can do it one at a time, and even have it in a .ps1 file and run it in Powershell for AWS and it runs correctly.

I am now trying to get this to install silently when the EC2 instance is created.  I just can't do it and I can't understand why.  The JSON code looks correct.  As you can see, I first download everything from the S3 bucket, switch to the c:\TEMP directory where they were all downloaded, then run the executables in unattended install mode.  I don't get any errors in my CloudFormation template. It runs "successfully."  The problem is that nothing happens.  Is it a permissions thing? Any help is welcome and appreciated.  Thanks!

Under the AWS::EC2::Instance section I have the UserData section looking something like this (I shortened the executable names below):

```
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
        "<powershell>\n",
        "copy-S3Object -BucketName mySilentInstallBucket -KeyPrefix * -LocalFolder c:\\TEMP\\",
        "\n",
        "cd c:\\TEMP\\",
        "\n",
        "firefox.exe -S ",
        "\n",
        "notepadpp.exe /S",
        "\n",
        "Git.exe /SILENT",
        "\n",
        "</powershell>"
    ]]}}
```

Comment: One thing that may help is to look at the System Log.  From the EC2 console, choose Actions - Monitor and Troubleshoot - Get System Log.  Then review it for the portion that runs the UserData and see what logs may reveal.  The CloudFormation template won't fail based on UserData errors (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373090/cloudformation-cfn-init-signal-success-failure-of-the-userdata-script).

Comment: Part of the issue was needing an instance Profile added to my EC2 Instance script information.  I am beginning to think there are other permissions issues involved here.  Will keep researching and trying and will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Network connectivity to the internet will be needed as well, so check your security groups and whether the instance has a path to the internet (or an endpoint for S3).  Look at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/ for many other things to check.

Answer (score 0):

This troubleshooting doc will cover the various reasons you may not be able to connect to S3: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/

> To connect to your S3 buckets from your EC2 instances, you need to do
> the following:
>
> 1. Create an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) profile role that grants access to Amazon S3.
> 2. Attach the IAM instance profile to the instance.
> 3. Validate permissions on your S3 bucket.
> 4. Validate network connectivity from the EC2 instance to Amazon S3.
> 5. Validate access to S3 buckets.

The CloudFormation template won't fail based on UserData execution exceptions.